# Regex Replace anything that does not match capturing group

Tags: regex, pascal

I have a String like following: `[Monster:Test]Maps=1,5,2,3[Monster:Test2]Maps=2-5`

I need to replace the string of unnecessary text.

The only text I want to keep is the brackets including the text between the brackets. So only `[Monster:Test]` and `[Monster:Test2]` should be kept.

So my regex to find it is: `\\[(.*)\\]`

I don't understand how to replace anything that does not match my group.

Comment: why not just join the matched elements ? also which programming language you're working on ?

Comment: The `.*` matches too much.  Instead of replacing, why not match them? `\[.*?\]` or  `\[[^\][]+\]` https://regex101.com/r/OVo8Ys/1

Comment: The language is Pascal, I use an environment SCAR Divi. Just joining them is fine!

Comment: Join := better; But if using replace `\][^\[\]]+\[` with `][`

Comment: What regular expression library are you using, and what regex variant does it support? That information is relevant. We'd already know that if you had provided a [mcve] of your code instead of just out of context information.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `preg_match_all`

```
$s = "[Monster:Test]Maps=1,5,2,3[Monster:Test2]Maps=2-5~";
preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]+\]/", $s, $m);
echo implode($m[0]);
```

Results into:

```
[Monster:Test][Monster:Test2]
```

Does this work as required?

Comment: This might work if the poster wasn't using Pascal. :-) There is no `$s` or `implode` or `preg_match` available.

Answer (score -1):

Just join all matches and you should end up with what you want.

```js
/\[[^\]]+\]/g;
```

- matches the first `[`
- matches anything that is not a `]`
- matches a `]`
- `g` flag for all matches

---

Implementation Example:

```js
var string = "[Monster:Test]Maps=1,5,2,3[Monster:Test2]Maps=2-5";
var result = string.match(/\[[^\]]+\]/g).join("");
console.log(result);
```

* Although the example is javascript, you should be able to do this in any other language.

Comment: I tried your regex, it works in js and probably everywhere else, just in SCAR Divi not, but that seems to be my problem for now. I used the regex for the method that is built in the environment but it just doesn't return anything.

Think there's  nothing to help anymore, thank you for helping.

Comment: @BastiOpa The last time I did anything in Pascal I used `TRegEx` have you tried it?